# How to make subscribers load balanced with Redis PubSub?

Tags: redis, message-queue

I am using Redis as message broker in pubsub mode.
There are only 1 publisher and N subscribers listening to same channel.
For the original pubsub mode, these N subscribers will receive "same" message each time.
My questions is, is there any mechanism inside Redis or any other ways for these subscribers get different   messages for each one ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Add messages to a Redis list, and multiple consumers use `BLPOP` and related commands to consume these messages.
2. Add messages to Redis Stream, and multiple consumers use `XREAD` and related commands to consume these messages.

Comment: Thanks. And I just read about rsmq project and this may do the trick, am I right ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with rsmq. You'd better check its doc for detail.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestion using RSMQ https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsmq may do the trick. Its correct tonyc. Just now I used it and it seems like can works fine. Replicated nodejs service app able to handle if both receive the message then justonly one service handle the process.